# Problems with paperclip on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

I've created a new project with Rails 5.0.0 and Ruby 2.5 on my local mac with  macOs 10.12. Now I'm trying to add paperclip to this project but still no luck.

My model class looks like this:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :file, styles: { big: '1280x1024>', small: '640x480>' }
  validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage/ }, file_name: { matches: [/png\Z/i, /jpe?g\Z/i, /gif\Z/i] }, size: { less_than: 15.megabytes }
end
```

Whatever version of paperclip I try I don't have a paperclip generator in my project and I'm geting errors like this when I try to call a model or it's methods:

```
"NoMethodError (undefined method `has_attached_file' for Photo (call 'Photo.connection' to establish a connection):Class)"
```

When I add "include Paperclip::Glue" like suggested here https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/705 error changes to

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Photo::Paperclip)
```

Is there any way for me to bypass this mess ? ><

Link to paperclip issues
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2555

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined method "has\_attached\_file" for my ActiveRecord model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326430/undefined-method-has-attached-file-for-my-activerecord-model)

Comment: Maybe, but there's still no real solution

Comment: okay, did you see the following links? => 1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527219/paperclip-has-attached-file-not-working-with-rails-establish-connection ***  2- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1909

Comment: Yep, no help. And yeah, reverting all migration and then terminating console and then migrating and then terminating again helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link provided by hamdi in the first comment is an answer.

If you've got problems with Devise or with Paperclip like that, don't try to add "include Paperclip::Glue" or in case of Devise "extend Devise::Models". The only right way to fix this is to rollback ALL of your migrations, terminate console, start it again, migrate, terminate console one more time and thats it! Sounds stupid but it's working >< Pictures upload is working and paperclip generator is on the list.

For all of you who came from Rails 4:

```
2.5.0 :001 > Photo
 => Photo (call 'Photo.connection' to establish a connection)
```

is totally ok behavior for console in Rails 5. Before accessing model you've got to perform 'Photo.connection' from now on. If you don't like it you can always fix it by adding

```
console do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection
end
```

to your config/application.rb